# How to download a file in wxWidgets with a progress dialog?

Tags: c++, dialog, download, progress-bar, wxwidgets

I have some code here that spawns a wxProgressDialog and downloads a file from the internet, but I can't figure out how to make the progress bar update as the file downloads. I've looked for documentation on this, but surprisingly I haven't been able to find something similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
void Downloader::Download(void)
{
    wxProgressDialog dlgProgress(_T("Downloading..."),
                                 _T("Please wait while your file downloads."));

    wxURL dl(Url);
    if (dl.GetError() == wxURL_NOERR)
    {
        wxInputStream *in = dl.GetInputStream();
        if (in && in->IsOk())
        {
            wxFFileOutputStream out(mPath);
            in->Read(out);
        }
        delete in;
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should explain how did you manage to not find the documentation for Update()...

Comment: Of course I did, but Update() isn't magic. My trouble is with keeping those updates in sync with the progress of the download.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "dialogs" sample in wxWidgets distribution and you'll see that you can call either [Update()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_generic_progress_dialog.html#a1d542cea96c531d85c32d6612bd55a02) or [Pulse()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_generic_progress_dialog.html#ab5ecf227eebaa1aadb5f5c553e4a4ee5) to update the dialog.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question- how do I track the download progress of a file as it downloads? I know how to update/pulse the progress bar.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question. But then you did write "can't figure out how to make the progress bar update". Anyhow, if you know the size of the file in advance you can read it in blocks of some size (4KB is common) and manage it like this. You can't do it by reading the entire stream using the Read() overload you do currently.